Getting error while selecting system assigned managed identity in data connection step of open ai data configuration
We tried to configure the data from the Blob storage by referring to the following link: Azure OpenAI On Your Data.
Based on the documentation, we enabled RBAC and provided the documented permissions for the resources, as well as for the developer who is manually configuring the data. However, we are still encountering the following error while validating the identity:

We have made all the services private by using VNet integration and private endpoints to connect to OpenAI, and the search service has also been created.
Also enabled 'Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account.' in storage account exceptions.

The error is mentioning that

The storage account disabled trusted service


Ensure the checkbox is selected for Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account as shown below:



Ensure that a system assigned identity is enabled in search service as shown below:



Ensure that the VNet integration and private endpoints are correctly set up and that there are no firewall rules blocking the connection between your services. Then you will be able to connect storage account successfully.
For more information you can refer to the MS document.


@Aiswarya Please check if the solution helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
